# Evento AJAX al cambiar Switch de Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, bootstrap

Teniendo la siguiente tabla HTML

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="miCheck">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="miCheck">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Necesito que al cambiar el valor del swith a `checked` se haga un llamado a una función con AJAX y este pase los datos a un documento PHP. Pero no logro que el resultado sea `Done`

Por lo tanto hago lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-check-input").on('change', function postinput() {
    var matchvalue = $(this).val(); // this.value
    $.ajax({
      url: 'validar.php',
      data: {
        matchvalue: matchvalue
      },
      type: 'post'
    }).done(function(responseData) {
      console.log('Done: ', responseData);
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('Failed');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="miswitch" onchange="postinput()">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-check form-switch">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" name="miswitch" onchange="postinput()">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Como pueden ver siempre me retorna `Failed` en consola

El archivo validar.php es tan sencillo como

```
$entry = $_POST['matchvalue'];
$conn->query("UPDATE matches SET grp = '$entry' WHERE mid = 'm1'");
```

Comment: Que dato necesitas capturar para enviar en la llamada? O sea que dato se depositaría en matchvalue al cambiar al quedar en checked?

Comment: En Javascript estás asignando un evento, elimina el `onclick` de las etiquetas para no duplicar y evitar conflictos. Por cierto, agrega el `value` a cada checkbox para obtener el dato correcto y evitar usar otros métodos.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero necesito recibir el ID, con eso me bastaría

Comment: @Triby me disculpo, no logro entender lo que me recomiendas :/ sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este código captura los datos nombre y apellido de la tabla, solo de una la fila chequeada, luego los envía en la llamada Ajax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td id="name1">Mark</td>
          <td id="lastname1">Otto</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                role="switch"
                name="miswitch"
                id="1"
                onchange="postInput(event)"
              />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila2">
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td id="name2">Jacob</td>
          <td id="lastname2">Thornton</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
              <input
                class="form-check-input"
                type="checkbox"
                role="switch"
                name="miswitch"
                id="2"
                onchange="postInput(event)"
              />
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      function postInput(event) {
        let nombre = document.getElementById(
          "name" + event.target.id
        ).innerHTML;
        let apellido = document.getElementById(
          "lastname" + event.target.id
        ).innerHTML;
        const matchvalue = nombre + " " + apellido;
        if (event.target.checked) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "validar.php",
            data: { matchvalue: matchvalue },
            success: function (responseData) {
              console.log("Done: ", responseData);
            },
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, y si quiero que el resultado se vea en el mismo documento donde tengo el formulario? PD: ya es un archivo con extension php

Comment: De nada, siempre es importante que en cada pregunta seas bien específico, des ejemplos, por ejemplo en este caso: Me gustaria que aparezca tal dato y tal otro que vienen de tal lado, quiero que se muestre de tal forma en tal lugar. La información nunca está de más y nos hará más fácil todo a todas las partes... Gracias